# is HikariCP be useful for MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-storm, hikaricp

i am trying to use HikariCP for mongodb to get best for db connections.
but HikariCP doesn't have driver for mongodb.

Let me know is that true? is there any possible way to integrate HikariCP  with mongodb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HikariCP` is a `JDBC` connection pool. You can't use it for NoSQL databases. It also doesn't have drivers for anything: it's a connection pool, so it uses JDBC drivers but you have to provide them.